# How to lock certain cells (columns of a table) but allow rows to be added?

Tags: excel, vba

I've a table where I lock 5 of the 10 columns so their formula is hidden and not editable. The code does a great job of hiding and editing.

I would like rows to be added.

- When I right-click on a cell in the table on the sheet itself, the option to insert a new table row is greyed out, despite "AllowInsertingRows:=True" being part of my protection.
- When I right-click on the left side of the page where the row numbers are, it pops up a "the cell or chart you are trying to change is on a protected sheet" error 5 times (I assume once for each of the 5 locked columns), then adds a row into the table, but the desired formula that would normally be inserted into a new table row doesn't exist.

I'm trying to do this so users are unable to "mess the table up."

photo of table I'm using since I don't know a better way to illustrate it for you
[image: photo of table I'm using since I don't know a better way to illustrate it for you]

```
Sub lockDesiredCellsInWeeklyTables()

Dim shtName As String
Dim tblName As String
Dim tbl As ListObject

dateName = "[Date]"
timeName = "[Time]"
phone1Name = "[Phone '#1]"
phone2Name = "[Phone '#2]"
phone3Name = "[Phone '#3]"

ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("april1")
    ' Locks the Date column
    Range(tbl & dateName).Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = True
    ' Locks the Time column
    Range(tbl & timeName).Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = True
    ' Locks the Phone #1 column
    Range(tbl & phone1Name).Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = True
    ' Locks the Phone #2 column
    Range(tbl & phone2Name).Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = True
    ' Locks the Phone #3 column
    Range(tbl & phone3Name).Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="1234", DrawingObjects:=False, _
                    Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False, _
                    AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
                    AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
                    AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, _
                    AllowDeletingColumns:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=True, _
                    AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
                    AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: 1st Step is unprotect the sheet - see if that allows adding a row. If that works put the unlock & Add Row into a macro and assign to abutton.Lots of ways around this problem

Comment: I would do that except the control sheet I use has macros, but the individual workbooks I'm using this macro on can't have macros enabled (they're saved in onedrive, which for whatever reason can't have macros). So technically I could unprotect the sheet to have no problem, but the users need to be able to add ONLY a row and not edit anything but the 5 unlocked columns. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is add the code you want to the Right-Click Menu - Rather than a button

First Add these 2 Routines to your existing Code - They Add to and Delete from the Right-Click Menu

```
Sub Add2RCMenu()
   '
   ' This will add items to the RightClick Menu
   ' Each will be Tagged with the Text "RCM" for ease of removal
   '
   Dim RClickMenu As CommandBar, dPos As Long
   Dim MyButn As CommandBarButton, LastButn As CommandBarButton

   ' Delete ALL pre-existing RCM controls first to avoid Duplicates.
     CleanRCMenu "RCM"
   ' Done

   Set RClickMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")
   dPos = RClickMenu.Controls.Count

   dPos = dPos + 1
   Set MyButn = RClickMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=dPos)
       MyButn.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!DoNothin"
       'MyButn.FaceId = 39
       MyButn.Caption = "*** Special Additions ***"
       MyButn.Tag = "RCM"
       MyButn.BeginGroup = True

   dPos = dPos + 1
   Set LastButn = RClickMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=dPos)
       LastButn.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!RCMAddNewRow"
       LastButn.FaceId = 18
       LastButn.Caption = "NEW Row"
       LastButn.Tag = "RCM"
       LastButn.BeginGroup = True
End Sub

Sub CleanRCMenu(GivnTag As String)
    ' Removes Items from the Right-Click Menu
    ' Items marked with a text tag

    Dim ContextMenu As CommandBar, xCtrl As CommandBarControl

    Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")
    For Each xCtrl In ContextMenu.Controls
        If GivnTag <> "" And xCtrl.Tag = GivnTag Then
            xCtrl.Delete
        End If
    Next xCtrl
End Sub
```

To accomodate those Menu Additions you need 2 new Subs - As follows (left empty for you to add the code you would have put on a button

```
Sub DoNothin()
   ' Self Explanatory - Does Nothing
End Sub

Sub RCMAddNewRow()
   ' Put whatever code you want here instead of on a button click
End Sub
```

Hope this helps